# Сannot get Float data type from NamedParameterJdbcTemplate

Tags: java, spring-jdbc

I just need to get a single `Float` data type value. In the PostgreSQL database, this field is of type `real`. I will be grateful)

```
`public Float getPlayerRatingValue(Integer idClub, Integer idPlayer) {
        MapSqlParameterSource parameters = new MapSqlParameterSource();
        parameters.addValue("idClub", idClub);
        parameters.addValue("idPlayer", idPlayer);
        parameters.addValue("zeroRating", ZERO_RATING);
        return namedParameterJdbcTemplate
                .queryForObject(
                        "SELECT rating_value " +
                                "FROM rating " +
                                "WHERE id_club = :idClub AND id_player = :idPlayer",
                        parameters,
                        new BeanPropertyRowMapper<>(Float.class)
                );`
```

Comment: Spring has special support for such queries, pass `Float.class` as the third parameter

Comment: did you try something ? which result ?

Comment: Of course, exc: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.lang.Float.<init>()

Comment: Hi Vadym. Generally its a great idea to share what you did to solve the problem and what did not work, preferably with error logs. This helps others as well to answer your query more aptly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NamedParameterJdbcTemplate` has a special [method](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html#queryForObject-java.lang.String-org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.SqlParameterSource-java.lang.Class-) for single row/column queries.

So you can just pass a `Float.class` as the third parameter:

```java
return namedParameterJdbcTemplate
        .queryForObject(
                "SELECT rating_value " +
                        "FROM rating " +
                        "WHERE id_club = :idClub AND id_player = :idPlayer",
                parameters,
                Float.class
        );
```

Another quick example:

```java
MapSqlParameterSource parameterSource = new MapSqlParameterSource();
Float f = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("SELECT CAST(1 AS REAL)", parameterSource, Float.class);
System.out.println(f);
```